# beginner... confused about same name variables within same function

Tags: php, oop, boolean

```
 1   <?php  
 2   class ACL  
 3   {  
 4       var $perms = array();        //Array : Stores the permissions for the user  
 5       var $userID = 0;            //Integer : Stores the ID of the current user  
 6       var $userRoles = array();    //Array : Stores the roles of the current user  
 7 
 8       function __constructor($userID = '')  
 9       {  
 10           if ($userID != '')  
 11          {  
 12               $this->userID = floatval($userID);  
 13           } else {  
 14               $this->userID = floatval($_SESSION['userID']);  
 15          }  
 16           $this->userRoles = $this->getUserRoles('ids');  
 17           $this->buildACL();  
 18       }
```

This is part of a tutorial I'm learning creating a login system. I don't know if I was at this for too long and my brain is fried but I'm getting confused about the boolean statement used as an argument in the function __constructor. See line 8.

This is the explanation given by the tutorial:

> The __constructor() function is used to initialize the object when we
>   want to load an ACL. It is called automatically when we call new
>   ACL();. It is then passed a single, optional argument of the user to
>   load the ACL for. Inside the constructor, we check to see if a user ID
>   was passed in. If no ID was passed, we assume that we will load the
>   ACL for the currently logged in user; so we read in the session
>   variable for that. Alternatively, if we pass in a user ID, it allows
>   us to read and edit the ACL for a user other than the one logged in
>   (useful for your admin page).

<s>Question #1... so this method is starting up as soon as you make a new class, and it is taking the boolean as an argument. I'm not understanding why you need to state the fact that userID = ' '. Couldn't you just make it simpler and write: function __constructor($userID) { if ($userID != '') ........etc. etc. ?? Or do they mean the same thing? 
The idea of stating a boolean never made sense to me, especially when you're not using it in an IF statement to test it's validity.</s>

EDIT: I made a very weird slip. Sorry disregard the whole boolean thing, it's not even a boolean statement. My error... 12 hours of learning programming is taking its toll.

Question 2: Is the variable $userID in line 5 the same as $userID in line8? I'm thinking no but I'm not sure. I'm sure that $userID on line 5 is the same as $this->userID on line 12 and line 15 but what about on line 8 and 10? I am confused. If the variable $userID on line 8 is NOT blank, then you are assigning $userID found on line 5 to the floatval of $userID on line 8??
I have a feeling that these are 2 different $userIDs. Why couldn't this guy just use a different word if that's the case? LOL

NOTE: I've been learning PHP for less than a week so these will seem like basic conceptual questions more than anything. Syntax isn't really a problem for me, it's the concepts.

Any help appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Why do think it is boolean? It even defaults to an empty string, so why do you assume it is a boolean variable??

Comment: Just a side note, it's `__construct()` not `__constructor()`.

Comment: Better to look for a tutorial that doesn't mix PHP4 and PHP5... a good PHP5 tutorial would assign "visiibility" to $perms, $userID and $userRoles, not simply use "var"

Comment: @Tom, thanks. It's an older tutorial but i've been using __construct().

Comment: @MarkBaker, thanks for pointing that out. I just put "public" instead of "var" to get into the habit of assigning "visibility" but am definitely looking for newer tutorials with PHP5. Still learning quite a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay,

1. The method is not used every time you "make a new class", it's called every time **an object is instantiated**, meaning every time the `new ClassName()` statement is called. The reason `function __construct($userID = '')` is used and not `function __construct($userID)`, is because we want to give it a **default value**. Meaning a user can either call `new APC()` or `new APC("userID")`.
2. No. The one declared on line 5 is an **object property**, it's a variable that exists within each object (meaning if you instantiate 2 APC classes, you would have one variable for each object created, 2 in total).
   The one on line 8 is a function argument. When the method is called with an argument (`new APC("userID")`) that argument will be stored in that variable inside of the function.
   It's coincidental that both of them have the same name.

Comment: Ah, yeah that's what I meant about "making a new class". I meant using the class ACL and instantiating it and "making" a new object of that class. My slip up there. 

Response to your answers:

1) OOOOOOOHHHHHH. I get it now. Want to give it a default value, and ability to call APC() or new APC("userID").. made it perfectly clear. Thank you. 


2) Thank you for clearing that up. Which brings me to ask, is it considered bad coding habit to use the same "names" such as in this case where the coder made the object property AND the function argument both the same thing? Or is it common?

Comment: I know that in the case of very small constructor functions (ie. just setting the variables, without taking any further action), I usually use same name variables. In situations where things may get sticky. I use different names for arguments and properties.

Answer (score 1):

It's not boolean. It's default value. So if you called function without parameter it considers `$userId` to be `""`.

Note `=` is an assignment operator and `==` is a comparison operator.

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb. I need to go to sleep.. I read it as a boolean, didn't even read it as a variable assigned to an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

question 1: `$userID` is passed as an optinal argument to the constructor function of the class. this means you can instantiate an object of this class either with our without passing the user id: 
example:

```
$acl = new ACL(); //valid
$acl = new ACL($aUersId); // also valid
```

question2: $userID in line 5 is a class property. it is accessed from the constructor in line 12 using `$this->userID`. $userID in line 10 is only exists inside the function.

Comment: Thanks, I had a slip up on question 1. Regarding question 2, so it is safe to say that userID in line 5/12/15 are the same and userID in line 10/12 only exists inside the function and is something else. It would be okay to rename it to $abcdef and there would be no problems? The fact that they are both called userID is very confusing to me.

Comment: $userID in line 5 can only be accessed from inside a function if you use $this->userID. everything that's called $userID inside the function you can rename to whatever you want and it won't affect anything

Comment: Thanks Stratton, that makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a boolean argument it is an argument with default value which is an empty string. If you not set a default value and you instantiate one object from this class it will throw an error becose one argument would be missing.

No, they aren't the same. One is an object variable and the other is an argument variable.

Be advised: this code is really old (var keyword, everthing is public, etc.)

Comment: Thanks peter. This was the only tutorial I could find that did an entire loginsystem with full explanation and source code but its back from 2008 or 2009. I'm not sure which elements need to be changed to private or protected since var is the same thing as public. but i guess I'll have to learn that some other time. 

Thanks for clearing up question 2.

Answer (score 1):

1.

```
function helloWorld($whattosay = 'Hello World') {
     echo $whattosay;
}

helloWorld()
// prints Hello World

helloWorld("kthxbai")
// prints kthxbai
```

2.

$this->userID  means "READ VARIABLE FROM LINE 5"

line10=line8

$this is the current (from inside) copy (instance) of the ACL class.

He does not use a different word because the idea is to communicate that whatever you put between () in new ACL() will become $this->userID in the copy (instance) of ACL.

Comment: Thanks, time to sleep! Good information about why he used the same word, I did not know that.